# Find the equations of the tangent lines to the ellipse with equation $4x^2+y^2=72$ that pass through the point $(4, 4)$.

Tags: calculus

Here is what I've done so far: $$4x^2+y^2=72$$
$$ Dx[4x^2+y^2] = Dx[72] $$
$$8x+2y*y'=0$$
$$y' = \frac{-4x}{y}$$
$$\frac{y-4}{x-4} = \frac{-4x}{y}$$
$$y^2-4y=-4x^2+16x$$

After this, I'm not sure how to proceed to find the points of tangency and eventually find the tagent lines. Any hints or help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Solutions: $y-6=-2(x-3)$ and $y-\frac{6}{5}=-14(x-\frac{21}{5})$

Comment: Be careful!  Where is this point $(x,y)$?  A general point on the ellipse?  A general point on your tangent line?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct until $\frac{y-4}{x-4}=\frac{-4x}{y}$.
In this equation, you give x,y on two sides different meaning. (x,y) on the left is any point on the tangent line, but(x,y) on the right is the tangent point on the eclipse where the line intersects.

To achieve your goal, let (x0, y0) be the tangent point, we have $4x0^2+y0^2=72$ and $\frac{y0-4}{x0-4}=\frac{-4x0}{y0}$. Two unknowns, two equations. Done.

Comment: Can you offer more hints on how to solve for the two unknowns afterwards? I just learned this and I'm super confused...

Comment: Turn the second equation into $4x0^2+y0^2-16x0-4y0=0$ and then substitute the terms of degree 2 with the first equation. You have $16x0+4y0=72$ now.

Answer (score 0):

This is complementary to Key Flex's answer

To obtain a relation between ellipse axes $(a,b)$ and slope and intercept $(m,c)$ of a straight line

$$ y= mx + c $$

and the ellipse in its standard form

$$ \dfrac {x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac {y^2}{b^2}= 1, $$

we eliminate $y$ between them to obtain a quadratic equation in $x$ which means we have two tangents. The discriminant should vanish for a coincident tangential double point, yielding result

$$ c^2= a^2 m^2+ b^2  $$

as tangency condition.

Comment: Do you know how to do it with implicit differentiation? That's the way I'm supposed to do it but I'm completely new to the topic